# Duplicate array values not working with Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, arrays, variables, simple-html-dom

I'm working with Simple HTML DOM like this:

```
foreach($html->find('img', 18) as $d) {
 echo $d->outertext;
}
```

Now I want to implement an array of variables, in this case images, so I did:

```
$img=array(

  "img"=>"18",
  "img"=>"21"

);


foreach($img as $x=>$x_value) 
{

  $d = $html->find($x, $x_value);
   echo $d->outertext;

}
```

The problem is that Simple HTML DOM is only returning the last image in array, which is number 21. What do I have to do to make it return everything in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because both items in your `$img` array has the same key. `foreach` doesn't recognize them as two seperate items because both keys are `img`.

Example code to demonstrate:

```
$test = array(
    "key" => 1,
    "key" => 2
);

echo "Length of array: " . count($test) . "\n\n";

echo "Items in array:\n";
foreach($test as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key => $value\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
Length of array: 1

Items in array:
key => 2
```

Comment: I found something over here [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp?output=print) `$img=array("img","img");
$arrlength=count($img);

for($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++)
  {
  
foreach($html->find($img[$x]) as $d) {
 echo $d->outertext;
}
  }`

Comment: It works because it can return the same value multiple times, however I cant seem to add the index number like this: "img, 3" Do you have any idea on how I can implement the index number? Do I have to create another array for this and merge the two?